# loading avro files with different schemas into one bigquery table

Tags: schema, google-bigquery, avro

I have a set of avro files with slightly varying schemas which I'd like to load into one bq table.

Is there a way to do that with one line? Every automatic way to handle schema difference would be fine for me.

Here is what I tried so far.

0) If I try to do it in a straightforward way, bq fails with error:

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO myproject:mydataset.logs gs://mybucket/logs/*
Waiting on bqjob_r4e484dc546c68744_0000015bcaa30f59_1 ... (4s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'iow-rnd:bqjob_r4e484dc546c68744_0000015bcaa30f59_1': The Apache Avro library failed to read data with the follwing error: EOF reached
```

1) Quick googling shows that there is --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION option which, added to bq load job, changes nothing. ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION does not change anything either.

2) Actually, schema id is mentioned in the file name, so files look like:

```
gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaA_*
gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaB_*
```

Unfortunately, bq load does not allow more that on asterisk (as is written in bq manual too):

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO myproject:mydataset.logs gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaA_*
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'iow-rnd:bqjob_r5e14bb6f3c7b6ec3_0000015bcaa641f3_1': Not found: Uris gs://otishutin-eu/imp/2016-06-27/*_schemaA_*
```

3) When I try to list the files explicitly, the list happens to be too long, so bq load does not work either:

```
 bq load --source_format=AVRO myproject:mydataset.logs $(gsutil ls gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaA_* | xargs | tr ' ' ',')
Too many positional args, still have ['gs://mybucket/logs/log_schemaA_2658.avro,gs://mybucket/logs/log_schemaA_2659.avro,gs://mybucket/logs/log_schemaA_2660.avro,...
```

4) When I try to use files as external table and list the files explicitly in external table definition, I also get "too many files" error:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: Table definition may not have more than 500 source_uris
```

I understand that I could first copy files to different folders and then process them folder-by-folder, and this is what I'm doing now as last resort, but this is only a small part of data processing pipeline, and copying is not acceptable as production solution.

Comment: BigQuery uses the schema from the last alphabetically sorted Avro file to read all the files. The error message in 0) indicates that the Avro library cannot use this schema to read all the Avro files. schema_update_option is to update the schema of the destination table after the data is read, so it won't help reading the data.

Can you load files with the same schema in one job? e.g., a job to load gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaA_*, another job to load gs://mybucket/logs/*_schemaB_*.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

The real file names look like this:

`gs://mybucket/2016-06-27.log._schemaA_.server-1_hash1.avro
gs://mybucket/2016-06-27.log._schemaA_.server-2_hash2.avro
...
gs://mybucket/2016-06-27.log._schemaA_.server-23_hash23.avro
...`


And looks like it is not possible to avoid two asterisks in file listing

Comment: Why is that? Won't gs://mybucket/2016-06-27.log._schemaA_*.avro work? Or you actually want to load multiple days at once so 2016-06-27 also needs to be replaced with a *?

Comment: Yes, it is not obvious from my example, there are multiple timestamps, schemes and hashes in the end of the filename and hash is generated for each file so it is more like 
gs://mybucket/2016-06-27-00-00-10.log._schemaA_.server-1_hash1.avro gs://mybucket/2016-06-27-00-00-09.log._schemaA_.server-2_hash2.avro ... gs://mybucket/2016-06-27-00-00-11.log._schemaA_.server-23_hash23.avro 
...
gs://mybucket/2016-06-27-00-01-11.log._schemaA_.server-1_hash123.avro
...